# pointer passing between functions fails with error

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to write two functions, one calls the other and passes in an argument:

```
int RegisterImage( const char * streamID, IMGStream & c ) {
...
}

int OpenImage( const char * streamid, int dsize ) {
ImageStream * im;
int idx = -1;

if ( GetImgRegIdx(streamid, dsize, im) )
          idx = RegisterImage (streamid, im);
return idx;
}
```

The calling of "RegisterImage()" fails. It complains about:
"in passing argument 2 of ‘int Core::RegisterImage(const char*, IMGStream&)’"

Can anybody help me understand why it's complaining, and how to fix it?
Thanks so much

Comment: What's the relationship between `IMGStream` and `ImageStream`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `IMGStream` and `ImageStream` objects are the same type (one being a typedef of the other or something), then the function is expecting a reference and you're passing a pointer.

So, if IMGStream and ImageStream objects are actually the same type, you should pass `*im` instead of `im`.

Answer (score 1):

`ImageStream * im;` is a pointer, your `RegisterIMage()` expects a reference as its second argument. You need to pass in `*im`. References implicitly refer to objects, not to addresses. Your `ImageStream*` is type that holds an address.

Answer (score 0):

It's asking for an `IMGStream&` which you read as 'IMGStream Reference'.  Although this acts very much like passing a pointer, the syntax **must not** be.

Try de-referencing your pointer with a `*` (the de-reference operator)

```
     idx = RegisterImage (streamid, *im);
```